# Toggle div depending on checkbox value - with animation

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a checkbox that when clicked shows/hides the content of a div using a  jQuery function.
I need the div to slide down (expanding the screen) rather than just appearing.

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#toggle1').change(function () {                
        $('#details1').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change(); //ensure visible state matches state of checkbox on page load
    });
</script>
```

If the checkbox (toggle1) is checked the div (details1) is displayed and vice versa.
Where do I put the animation effect?

Comment: `toggle` -> [`slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: It's nice that someone edited the question, then gives a negative vote because it shows lack of research or is unclear! What sort of forum is this?
The line "I'm missing something obvious here" obviously went right over their head!

Comment: Thanks Rory, but slideToggle does not work as expected. It ignores the checkbox state. Although the toggle works when you click the checkbox, when the page loads the div is displayed, I need it hidden and only displayed if the checkbox is ticked - which is an optional parameter passed into the page when it loads.

Comment: You're right, `slideToggle` doesn't quite work in that way. I've added an answer for you with an example which covers your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> slideToggle does not work as expected. It ignores the checkbox state

That's true, because `slideToggle()` annoyingly doesn't accept a boolean in the same way `toggle()` does. As such you would need to check state of the checkbox and use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` separately.

> When the page loads the div is displayed, I need it hidden and only displayed if the checkbox is ticked

In this case use CSS to hide the elements on load as that does not require the page to load first as JS does. If you want to show the content on load without the slide animation use `show()`.

Here's a full working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $toggle =$('#toggle1').change(e => {    
    $('#details1')[e.target.checked ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
  })
  
  if ($toggle.is(':checked'))
    $('#details1').show();
});
```

```css
#details1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" checked />
<div id="details1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```